# How to test for JSONException in JUnit Test?

Tags: java, junit

I would like to test for JSONException in the following method but was unable to achieve it. The following is my implementation:

The method `formatresponse` within `methodA` has added the key(UtilClass.Object.YEAR) to the JSONObject, therefore, it is not possible that the key is not present as there aren't other methods within the class to remove the key. I have tried mocking using the mockito framework to throw the JSONException but was not successful in throwing the exception using either `thenThrow` or `doThrow`.

```
private JSONObject response;

public ReturnType methodA(JsonObject request, String ipAddr) {

      formatResponse(UtilClass.Object.YEAR, new JSONObject());

      for (int i = 0; i < computedYear.length; i++) {

         try {
              response.getJSONObject(UtilClass.Object.YEAR).put(computedYear[i], new JSONObject()); <== How do I unit test for this line?
         } catch (JSONException e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage())
         }

}

private void formatResponse(String key, Object value) {
     try {
         response.put(key, value);
     } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

The following is my junit code:

```
private String ipAddr = "127.0.0.1";

public void testMethodA() {

     ClassA classAInstance = mock(ClassA.class);
     Mockito.doThrow(JSONException.class).when(classAInstance).methodA(request, ipAddr);

     classInstance.methodA(request, ipAddr);
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any form of help or sharing of knowledge if you have encountered the following issue previously. Thank you!

Comment: Please share the junit code as well. What is the value of `response` in your junit?

Comment: I have added in my junit test. In this case, response is {"year", {}} and UtilClass.Object.YEAR value is "year"

Comment: What if you use a `response` such as `{}` and do not mock anything?

Comment: It's not possible as I have written above. The method formatresponse within methodA has added the key(UtilClass.Object.YEAR) to the JSONObject, therefore, it is not possible that the key is not present as there aren't other methods within the class to remove the key.

Comment: You can mock the response object and throw JSONException when getJSONObject is called

Comment: Is it possible to show a code snippet of what you mentioned above?

Comment: `Mockito.doThrow(JSONException.class).when(response).getJSONObject(UtilClass.Object.YEAR).put(computedYear[i], new JSONObject());` And `response` should be mocked in the same way you are mocking `classAInstance`